# How to know the exact block size of a file on a Hadoop node?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a `1 GB` file that I've put on `HDFS`. So, it would be broken into blocks and sent to different nodes in the cluster.

Is there any command to identify the exact size of the block of the file on a particular node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `hdfs fsck` command:

```
hdfs fsck /tmp/test.txt -files -blocks
```

This command will print information about all the blocks of which file consists:

```
/tmp/test.tar.gz 151937000 bytes, 2 block(s):  OK
0. BP-739546456-192.168.20.1-1455713910789:blk_1073742021_1197 len=134217728 Live_repl=3
1. BP-739546456-192.168.20.1-1455713910789:blk_1073742022_1198 len=17719272 Live_repl=3
```

As you can see here is shown (`len` field in every row) actual used capacities of blocks.

Also there are many another useful features of `hdfs fsck` which you can see at the official [Hadoop documentation page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#fsck).

Comment: I've setup a 2 node hadoop cluster. And, I'm trying to test if master communicating with slave or not?

So, I copied a file(159 MB) in HDFS. Now, it should be divided into 2 blocks, 1 on each node. When I run fsck command, I get this:
/abc.txt 166612212 bytes, 2 block(s):  Under replicated BP-531753399-127.0.1.1-1455542244078:blk_1073741826_1002. Target Replicas is 2 but found 1 replica(s).
 Under replicated BP-531753399-127.0.1.1-1455542244078:blk_1073741827_1003. Target Replicas is 2 but found 1 replica(s).

Let me know why is my set-up not working properly? Is there any better way?

Comment: The easiest way to monitor your HDFS health is to use `hdfs dfsadmin -report` command. If you see that not all of your datanodes have started than try to check logs of that datanodes.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.blocksize
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have reputation to comment.

Have a look at [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) page to set various properties, which covers

```
dfs.blocksize
```

Apart from configuration change, you can view actual size of file with

```
hadoop fs -ls fileNameWithPath
```

e.g.

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/edureka
```

output:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 edureka supergroup     391355 2014-09-30 12:29 /user/edureka/cust
```